# How to get the form beside the paragraph?

Tags: html, css

Link to my code:
https://codepen.io/vindhya97/pen/GRZgBBj
How to get the form beside the paragraph?
I have tried using float:right yet it not coming.I have searched in internet but, information regarding this is not available. Can anybody help me with this?
Above there is link to my code.

```
      <div class="signin">
      <div id="about">About :</div>
      <div id="about1">This is a website for writers to publish new      <br>.user-generated stories. It aims to create social <br>communities around stories<br> for both amateur and<br> established writers</div>
      <form  style="border:1px solid #ccc; margin-left: 600px; position: absolute; left: 150px;">
      <div class="container">
      <h1>Sign Up</h1>
      <p>Please fill in this form to create an account.</p>
      <hr>

      <label for="email"><b>Email</b></label>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Email" name="email" required>

    <label for="psw"><b>Password</b></label>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" required>

    <label for="psw-repeat"><b>Repeat Password</b></label>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Repeat Password" name="psw-repeat" required>

    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="remember" style="margin-bottom:15px"> Remember me
    </label>

   <p>By creating an account you agree to our <a href="#" style="color:dodgerblue">Terms & Privacy</a>.</p>

   <div class="clearfix">
      <button type="button" class="cancelbtn">Cancel</button>
      <button type="submit" class="signupbtn">Sign Up</button>
   </div>
</div>
```

```
#hyplink{
   float:right;
   margin-right: 10px;
   margin-top: 0px
   }
#about{
  font-size: 45px;
  margin-left: 30px;
 }
#about1{
  font-size: 30px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  }
.signin{
  float:left;
 }
 input[type=text], input[type=password] {
     width: 100%;
     padding: 15px;
     margin: 5px 0 22px 0;
     display: inline-block;
     border: none;
     background: #f1f1f1;
   }
 input[type=text]:focus, input[type=password]:focus {
     background-color: #ddd;
     outline: none;
    }

 hr {
   border: 1px solid #f1f1f1;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `display: inline-block`, remove `position: absolute`, set the width of both elements, and `vertical-align` the text:

```css
body {
  background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1533035336122-4327d347d2fe?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1050&q=80");
}

img {
  width: 20%;
  height: auto;
  padding: 1%;
  float: left;
}

h1 {
  margin: 45px;
  color: red;
  font-size: 55px;
  font-family: Georgia;
}

.img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  padding: 1%;
}

#hyplink {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

#about {
  font-size: 45px;
  margin-left: 30px;
}

#about1 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: calc(50% - 60px);
  font-size: 30px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  vertical-align: top;
}

form {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
}

input[type="text"],
input[type="password"] {
  width: calc(100% - 30px);
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 5px 0 22px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  border: none;
  background: #f1f1f1;
}

input[type="text"]:focus,
input[type="password"]:focus {
  background-color: #ddd;
  outline: none;
}

hr {
  border: 1px solid #f1f1f1;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

button {
  background-color: #4caf50;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0.9;
}

button:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.cancelbtn {
  padding: 14px 20px;
  background-color: #f44336;
}

.cancelbtn,
.signupbtn {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}

.container {
  padding: 16px;
}

.clearfix::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}
```

```html
<!<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Stories</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="lab2.css" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class=img>
    <div id="hyplink">
      <h4><a href="./home.html">  Home  </a>|
        <a href=./item1.html>  Item 1  </a>|
        <a href="./item2.html">  Item 2  </a>|
        <a href="./contact.html">  Contact US</a></h4>
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="https://www.nostellgia.com/admin/uploads/your-story-1024x4555735476.jpg">
    </div>
    <div id="heading" style='margin-left:60px;'>
      <h1>What's Your Story</h1>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="signin">
    <div id="about">About :</div>
    <div id="about1">This is a website for writers to publish new user-generated stories. It aims to create social communities around stories for both amateur and established writers</div>
    <form style="border:1px solid #ccc;">
      <div class="container">
        <h1>Sign Up</h1>
        <p>Please fill in this form to create an account.</p>
        <hr>

        <label for="email"><b>Email</b></label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Email" name="email" required>

        <label for="psw"><b>Password</b></label>
        <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" required>

        <label for="psw-repeat"><b>Repeat Password</b></label>
        <input type="password" placeholder="Repeat Password" name="psw-repeat" required>

        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="remember" style="margin-bottom:15px"> Remember me
        </label>

        <p>By creating an account you agree to our <a href="#" style="color:dodgerblue">Terms & Privacy</a>.</p>

        <div class="clearfix">
          <button type="button" class="cancelbtn">Cancel</button>
          <button type="submit" class="signupbtn">Sign Up</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: perfect!! Thank you :)

Comment: No problem @Vindhya

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use absolute positioning in this case. Try using `grid`

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 2fr 1fr;
}

form {
  border: solid 1px;
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div>Your paragraph here</div>
  <form>
    Your form here
  </form
</div>
```

Comment: However browser support isn't the best in the world: [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#search=grid). Still an extremely good idea :)

Comment: @sven how old of a browser are you supporting? cause grid has 93% browser support https://caniuse.com/#search=grid

Comment: ie6 - oh yes :-)

Answer (score 0):

html:

```
<div id="about">About :</div>
<br>
<div>
<div style="display:inline-block;" id="about1">This is a website for writers to publish new <br>user-generated stories. It aims to create social <br>communities around stories<br> for both amateur and<br> established writers</div>

<div style="display:inline-block;float:right;">
 <form  style="border:1px solid #ccc;max-width:800px;padding: 10px;">
  
    <h1>Sign Up</h1>
    <p>Please fill in this form to create an account.</p>
    <hr>

    <label for="email"><b>Email</b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Email" name="email" required>

    <label for="psw"><b>Password</b></label>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" required>

    <label for="psw-repeat"><b>Repeat Password</b></label>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Repeat Password" name="psw-repeat" required>

    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="remember" style="margin-bottom:15px"> Remember me
    </label>

   <p>By creating an account you agree to our <a href="#" style="color:dodgerblue">Terms & Privacy</a>.</p>

   <div class="clearfix">
      <button type="button" class="cancelbtn">Cancel</button>
      <button type="submit" class="signupbtn">Sign Up</button>
   </div>
```

And then just removed the signin class from the css.
Does that work?